# Filebeat kafka input using multiline parser gives no output

Tags: apache-kafka, multiline, filebeat, elastic-beats

Filebeat is configured to use input from kafka and output to file

When the multiline setting is turned off, the output is published to a file.
But when kafka input is configured with **mutiline**, no output in the file(file is not even created)

Here is relevant filebeat configuration

Input configuration

```
filebeat.inputs:
  - type: kafka
    hosts:
      - <ip>:9092
    topics:
      - "my-multiline-log"
    group_id: "kafka-consumer-filebeat"
    parsers:
      - multiline:
          #          type: pattern
          pattern: '^'
          negate: true
          match: after
```

Output Configuration:

```
output.file:
  path: "/tmp/filebeat"
  filename: filebeat
#  codec.format:
#    string: '%{[message]}'
```

Filebeat relevant logs

```
2021-12-16T11:02:34.551Z    INFO    [input.kafka]   compat/compat.go:111    Input kafka starting    {"id": "19A7FFEEC9EDFC04"}
2021-12-16T11:02:34.551Z    INFO    [input.kafka.kafka input]   kafka/input.go:129  Starting Kafka input    {"id": "19A7FFEEC9EDFC04", "hosts": ["<ip>:9092"]}
2021-12-16T11:02:38.158Z    DEBUG   [reader_multiline]  multiline/pattern.go:142    Multiline event flushed because timeout reached.
2021-12-16T11:02:44.767Z    DEBUG   [reader_multiline]  multiline/pattern.go:142    Multiline event flushed because timeout reached.
2021-12-16T11:02:51.481Z    DEBUG   [reader_multiline]  multiline/pattern.go:142    Multiline event flushed because timeout reached.
2021-12-16T11:02:58.225Z    DEBUG   [reader_multiline]  multiline/pattern.go:142    Multiline event flushed because timeout reached.
2021-12-16T11:03:04.555Z    DEBUG   cgroup/util.go:276  PID 1 contains a cgroups V2 path (0::/) but no V2 mountpoint was found.
This may be because metricbeat is running inside a container on a hybrid system.
To monitor cgroups V2 processess in this way, mount the unified (V2) hierarchy inside
the container as /sys/fs/cgroup/unified and start metricbeat with --system.hostfs.
```

Getting same four line of `reader_multiline` in the logs repeated

Edit: The support for multiline parser for kafka has been added in version 7.16

Comment: You need to show the Kafka data. Record values wouldn't be "multi-line", but they may include new-line characters, which you would need to **split**, not "parse"

Answer (score 0):

I think this config is unnecessary. The pattern: `pattern: '^'` is not able to match any line.

```yaml
      - multiline:
          type: pattern
          pattern: '^'
          negate: true
          match: after
```

You can refer [this go playground](https://go.dev/play/p/LT3wWiFBdhK) to play with the pattern and log-lines, it is a tweaked version of playground mentioned in the filebeat's official [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/multiline-examples.html#_test_your_regexp_pattern_for_multiline)

As I could see the above provided pattern does not match any log line. Also, for splitting by new line, you don't even need to configure `multiline` parser, it is the default behavior.